# Access-Control-Allow-Origin in post request - Node

Tags: node.js, cors

I am getting a CORS error while POST request,
my server is Nodejs looks like :

```
    var express = require('express');
var app = express();
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/public'));

app.use(function(request, response, next) {
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'GET,PUT,POST,DELETE,OPTIONS');
    response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Headers', 'Content-Type, Authorization, Content-Length, X-Requested-With');

  next();
});

app.post('/InsertClient', function(request, response){

  console.log(request.body);      // your JSON
  response.send(request.body);    // echo the result back

});
```

I've try to set the headers already..
any ideas?
Thank you all!

Comment: You might want to use this small module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/cors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should add a `OPTIONS` route at the same url as the `POST`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS

Something like:

```
app.options('/InsertClient', function(request, response){
  response.sendStatus(200);
});
```

The browser will then first call the url with the `OPTIONS` method and check if it has all the appropriate cors flags, then make the actual `POST` request.